# VBscripts and wildcards

Tags: vba, vbscript, vb6

help would be great as i am clueless. New to VBscripts and to create a VBscripts that would find a file that has a wildcard in the name and look for a patterns within it and copy that info into another file that it creates.But what i get is a blank file

```
    Const ForReading = 1
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "DETECTION"

Const ForWriting = 2

strFolderName = "c:"
strTargetFile = "C:\race\master.txt"
strFileNameConstant = "Master"  
strComputer = "."



objregex.global = true
objregex.ignorecase = true
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSubfolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='" & strFolderName & "'} " _
        & "Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory " & "ResultRole = PartComponent")

arrFolderPath = Split(strFolderName, "\")
strNewPath = ""
For i = 1 to Ubound(arrFolderPath)
    strNewPath = strNewPath & "\\" & arrFolderPath(i)
Next
strPath = strNewPath & "\\"

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from CIM_DataFile where Path = '" & strPath & "'")

For Each objFile in colFiles

    If InStr(Lcase(objFile.Name),LCase(strFileNameConstant)) Then

        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, 1)
        strSearchString = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
        Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        objRegEx.Global = True  
        objRegEx.Pattern = "DETECTION"
        strNewText = objRegEx.Replace(strSearchString,VBCrlf & "DETECTION" & VBCrLf) 

    End If

Next
'Writes Target file
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTargetFile, ForWriting, true)
objFile.WriteLine(strNewText)
objFile.Close
```

**Update: what the code does is that it reads a log file (master) that can at times have wild cards in its name (master-123.123.txt) and looks for a Pattern (detection) and then creates another file with the rows that had the phrase "detection" in them. what it is currently doing is that its creating the file but not including the rows that have the phrase "detection in them". Im not sure as to what im doing wrong as i get no errors and the code. It creates the file and is able to find the master file even if it has wild cards in it.

Comment: Can you explain it more. didn't get the idea. some examples would help a lot

Comment: what the code does is that it reads a log file (master) that can at times have wild cards in its name (master-123.123.txt) and looks for a Pattern (detection) and then creates another file with the rows that had the phrase "detection" in them. what it is currently doing is that its creating the file but not including the rows that have the phrase "detection in them" and im not sure why.

Comment: Your RegEX doesn't seems work right. try changing it. i I tried with this ".*detection+.*"

And are you sure that your script find the master file?

Comment: I ran some tests and it seems that it doesn't find/look for the master file. It just creates a file called master. I know because i removed the file and i didn't get an error and it still created the file with what it found. i was expecting an error but i didn't get one.  Which may be my problem. since its not looking for the file and just creating one. At least that's it looks like to me.

Comment: change your file path. its worked for me. and you don't get any error message there is no error and u dont get the expected result because you may doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here what i did. Note that some parts have being changed. 
strFolderName is the path where we put the master file. this code will read the master file and get lines which "detection" word appears and write those line into a new file called master.txt(thats what i get from your question). if you need to do something else try changing regex.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "DETECTION"

Const ForWriting = 2

strFolderName = "D:\Vbs\StackOverflow"
strTargetFile = "master.txt"
strFileNameConstant = "Master"  
strComputer = "."

objregex.global = true
objregex.ignorecase = true
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSubfolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='" & strFolderName & "'} " _
        & "Where AssocClass = Win32_Subdirectory " & "ResultRole = PartComponent")

arrFolderPath = Split(strFolderName, "\")
strNewPath = ""
For i = 1 to Ubound(arrFolderPath)
    strNewPath = strNewPath & "\\" & arrFolderPath(i)
Next
strPath = strNewPath & "\\"

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from CIM_DataFile where Path = '" & strPath & "'")

For Each objFile in colFiles
    If InStr(Lcase(objFile.Name),LCase(strFileNameConstant)) Then

        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, 1)
        strSearchString = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
        Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        objRegEx.Global = True  
        objRegEx.Pattern = ".*detection+.*"
        set strNewText = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString) 
    End If

Next
'Writes Target file
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTargetFile, ForWriting, true)
for each maches in strNewText
objFile.Write maches
next
objFile.Close
```